# Matching a method signature with a unknown parameter in a mocked class

Tags: dart, mockito, flutter-test

I have this method:

```
Future<Either<Failure, WorkEntity>> updateWorkEntity({int id, String title, TimeType timeType, int times, DateTime executed})
```

that is being called like this:

```
repository.updateWorkEntity(id: workEntity.id, executed: DateTime.now())
```

the id I can control in a test, but the "DateTime.now()" I ofcourse can not. What I tried was this in my test:

```
when(repository.updateWorkEntity(id: expected.id, executed: any)).thenAnswer((_) async => Right(expected));
```

to be able to make my mock return a object for my test, by using "any" in the place of the "DateTime.now()", but I get this error:

> Invalid argument(s): The "any" argument matcher is used outside of
>   method stubbing (via `when`) or verification (via `verify` or
>   `untilCalled`). This is invalid, and results in bad behavior during
>   the next stubbing or verification.

So I guess I can not use any here, but then how do I get my mock to return an object when I do not control one of the input parameters?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `executed: anyNamed('executed')` instead of `executed: any`